# How to select multiple files with a java plugin and then upload with PHP?

Tags: java, php

I am looking a easy way for the user to upload multiple images to the website. The idea I have on mind is like the old Facebook service that, I think, they used Java. You click to add images and popups with a your system files and folders where you can select with checkboxes more than one image, only one, etc.

I have never used something like that, and I also didn't touched Java but i think that is the only way to do it.

Thanks!

PS: I'm not talking about multiple `<input type="file" />`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash is a more common choice than Java these days (it has a significantly wider reach). YUI provides [a widget](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/uploader/) to do this, [SWFUploader](http://www.swfupload.org/) provides a more generic widget (i.e. not tied to a larger library).

Comment: Dorward: thanks! Seems that this example http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/uploader/uploader-advanced-queue.html will work for me!! :)

PS: I've to wait 8min to accept your answer... so 1 moment please ;)